# Should I be updating aria-* attributes with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wai-aria

Let's say I have the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p {
    display:none;
}
input:focus + p {
    display:block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input />
<p aria-hidden="true">This field should not exceed 200 characters.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I put my mouse cursor into the `input` field, the paragraph appears.  However, the paragraph still has the attribute `aria-hidden="true"` despite being visible.

In terms of web accessibility, should I be introducing JavaScript code that will explicitly toggle the `aria-hidden` between `true` or `false` depending on whether my CSS rules shows or hides the paragraph tag?

I'm trying to wrap my head around how these `aria` attributes are used, and whether they imply the need of a JavaScript developer to add additional code that alters the HTML mark up in a way that reflects the behaviour described by my CSS.

Comment: I'd ask whether you should be hiding that paragraph in the first place. Screen reader users probably aren't as interested in hover behaviors. If you are going to hide it, unhiding is probably important, but so is the use of other ARIA attributes to draw attention to the new content.

Comment: Also, if you have jQuery available the scripting is trivial to do that sort of thing. Even a lowly markup author could quickly learn to do it. :P

Comment: @isherwood the example above is only an example of other things.  So are you saying basically when state changes as the result of CSS rules, new javascript code should be introduced to modify aria-* attributes to reflect CSS behaviours? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your particular example is a little weird, but in general, yes, javascript should be used to change the value of the aria attributes.  Just like you can use JS to change the value of any element attribute.

If you had a custom checkbox such as `<span role='checkbox' aria-checked='false'>` (*), then you'd need JS to change the value of aria-checked from FALSE to TRUE when the checkbox is selected (and vice versa, of course).

(*) If you have a custom checkbox, you're going to have several other attributes that are not shown here, such as tabindex, mouse and keyboard handlers, etc.